# Singleton class Instantiation: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, singleton

I'am trying to implement Singleton class. This is my code:

```
class ImageUtils:
__instance = None
def __init__(self):  
   """ Virtually private constructor. """
   if ImageUtils.__instance != None:
     raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
   else:
     ImageUtils.__instance = self          

@staticmethod
def getInstance():
    """Static access method"""
    if ImageUtils.getInstance() == None:
        ImageUtils()
    return ImageUtils.__instance
```

I test it like this:

```
s = ImageUtils()
print(s)

s = ImageUtils.getInstance()
print(s)

s = ImageUtils.getInstance()
print(s)
```

I get this error:

> ```
> if ImageUtils.getInstance() == None: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
> ```

Now, when I test the code here: [Python Design Pattern Singletons](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm), it gives me the expected result of printing the Singleton instance's memory location, three times.

Question: When I copy and paste the code given in the link, I get the expected result. However, the implementation of the ImageUtils class gives me RecursionError. Why is that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Think about what happens when you call `getInstance()`. Go through line by line.

Comment: Thank you! I am calling getInstance recursively. Wasn't intentional

Answer (score 0):

In the `def getInstance():`

```
if ImageUtils.getInstance() == None
```

should instead be

```
if ImageUtils.__instance == None
```